# Can the current value of a variable be used as the Key for another variable in Postman?

Tags: postman

I want to be able to extract the value of a pre-set variable and use it as the Key for the next variable.

As part of my set up I have declared the first variable as

```
pm.environment.set("uuid", "1eb253c");
```

Which sets UUID, I then want to use the value stored in UUID (1eb253c) as the Key for the second variable.

So that I at the end of the process I have two variables:

1. UUID with a value of 1eb253c

AND

2. 1eb253c with a value that is extracted from the response

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by:

```
var role_data = pm.response.json().results[0];
postman.setGlobalVariable(pm.environment.get("uuid"), role_data.role_category_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

After declaring your environment variable `uuid` try declaring another environment variable that uses the value of "uuid" as the key and the request's response as its value:

```
pm.environment.set(pm.environment.get("uuid"), pm.response)
```